# Select 2 issue while showing records

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am implementing select 2 in remote mode, data is coming , but not displaying in dropdown, can anyone point out the mistake i am doing?

when records came from DB, the dropdown hidea and don't show anything...

```
<select class="productName inputjob" name="productName" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$( ".productName" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/jobsite/get_json_data",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

JSON RECORDS COMING:

```
[{"skID":"851","skVal":"Aeroelasticity"},{"skID":"1363","skVal":"Amazon Elastic MapReduce"},{"skID":"1615","skVal":"Angioplasty"},{"skID":"1655","skVal":"Animation Master"},{"skID":"1778","skVal":"Anycast"},{"skID":"1946","skVal":"Application Infrastructure"},{"skID":"1947","skVal":"Application Infrastructure Design"},{"skID":"2305","skVal":"Arthroplasty"},{"skID":"2607","skVal":"Asta Power Project"},{"skID":"2608","skVal":"Asta Powerproject"},{"skID":"2609","skVal":"Astah"},{"skID":"2610","skVal":"Astaro"},{"skID":"2611","skVal":"ASTD Member"},{"skID":"2612","skVal":"Asterisk"},{"skID":"2613","skVal":"Asterisks"},{"skID":"2614","skVal":"Asterix"},{"skID":"2615","skVal":"Asthma"},{"skID":"2616","skVal":"ASTM"},{"skID":"2617","skVal":"ASTM standards"},{"skID":"2618","skVal":"Aston Martin"},{"skID":"2619","skVal":"Astra"},{"skID":"2620","skVal":"Astro"},{"skID":"2621","skVal":"Astrobiology"},{"skID":"2622","skVal":"Astrodynamics"},{"skID":"2623","skVal":"Astrology"},{"skID":"2624","skVal":"Astronautics"},{"skID":"2625","skVal":"Astronomy"},{"skID":"2626","skVal":"Astrophysics"},{"skID":"2627","skVal":"Astute"},{"skID":"2628","skVal":"Astute Graphics"},{"skID":"2794","skVal":"Audio Mastering"},{"skID":"3033","skVal":"Avast"},{"skID":"3128","skVal":"AWS Elastic Beanstalk"},{"skID":"3303","skVal":"Ballasts"},{"skID":"3564","skVal":"Beast"},{"skID":"3967","skVal":"Bioplastics"},{"skID":"4074","skVal":"BLAST"},{"skID":"4075","skVal":"Blastcode"},{"skID":"4076","skVal":"Blasting"},{"skID":"4090","skVal":"Blepharoplasty"},{"skID":"4356","skVal":"BookMaster"},{"skID":"4613","skVal":"Breakfast"},{"skID":"4622","skVal":"Breast"},{"skID":"4623","skVal":"Breast Augmentation"},{"skID":"4624","skVal":"Breast Cancer"},{"skID":"4625","skVal":"Breast Cancer Research"},{"skID":"4626","skVal":"Breast Health"},{"skID":"4627","skVal":"Breast Imaging"},{"skID":"4628","skVal":"Breast Implants"},{"skID":"4629","skVal":"Breast Reconstruction"},{"skID":"4630","skVal":"Breast Reduction"},{"skID":"4631","skVal":"Breast Surgery"},{"skID":"4632","skVal":"Breastfeeding"},{"skID":"4701","skVal":"Broadcast"},{"skID":"4702","skVal":"Broadcast Advertising"},{"skID":"4703","skVal":"Broadcast Agent"},{"skID":"4704","skVal":"Broadcast Automation"},{"skID":"4705","skVal":"Broadcast Design"},{"skID":"4706","skVal":"Broadcast Engineering"},{"skID":"4707","skVal":"Broadcast Journalism"},{"skID":"4708","skVal":"Broadcast Management"},{"skID":"4709","skVal":"Broadcast Media Sales"},{"skID":"4710","skVal":"Broadcast Operations"},{"skID":"4711","skVal":"Broadcast Pix"},{"skID":"4712","skVal":"Broadcast Production"},{"skID":"4713","skVal":"Broadcast Standards"},{"skID":"4714","skVal":"Broadcast Television"},{"skID":"4715","skVal":"Broadcast Traffic"},{"skID":"4716","skVal":"Broadcast Writing"},{"skID":"4717","skVal":"Broadcasting"},{"skID":"4749","skVal":"Bronze Casting"},{"skID":"4817","skVal":"Budget Forecast"},{"skID":"4818","skVal":"Budget Forecasts"},{"skID":"4842","skVal":"Budgeting & Forecasting"},{"skID":"4917","skVal":"Building Long Lasting Relationships"},{"skID":"5066","skVal":"Business Continuity\/Disaster Recovery"},{"skID":"5477","skVal":"Cadastral"},{"skID":"5807","skVal":"Capital Forecasting"},{"skID":"5936","skVal":"Carecast"},{"skID":"6069","skVal":"Cash Flow Forecasting"},{"skID":"6101","skVal":"Cast"},{"skID":"6102","skVal":"Cast Iron"},{"skID":"6103","skVal":"Cast Stone"},{"skID":"6104","skVal":"Casting"},{"skID":"6105","skVal":"Castings"},{"skID":"6106","skVal":"Castle"},{"skID":"6107","skVal":"Castle Rock"},{"skID":"6108","skVal":"Castle Windsor"},{"skID":"6109","skVal":"Castor"},{"skID":"6149","skVal":"Catastrophe Insurance"},{"skID":"6150","skVal":"Catastrophe Modeling"},{"skID":"6151","skVal":"Catastrophic"},{"skID":"6152","skVal":"Catastrophic Loss"},{"skID":"6153","skVal":"Catastrophic Personal Injury"},{"skID":"6271","skVal":"CD Mastering"},{"skID":"6568","skVal":"Certified Scrum Master CSM"},{"skID":"6782","skVal":"Charge Description Master"},{"skID":"6784","skVal":"Charge Master"},{"skID":"6788","skVal":"Chargemaster"},{"skID":"7862","skVal":"Coast Guard"},{"skID":"7863","skVal":"Coastal"},{"skID":"7864","skVal":"Coastal Engineering"},{"skID":"7865","skVal":"Coastal Management"},{"skID":"7866","skVal":"Coastal Processes"},{"skID":"7867","skVal":"Coastal Properties"},{"skID":"7868","skVal":"Coastal Zone Management"},{"skID":"7869","skVal":"Coasters"},{"skID":"7943","skVal":"Coffee Roasting"},{"skID":"8400","skVal":"Communications Infrastructure"},{"skID":"8460","skVal":"Community Master Planning"},{"skID":"9463","skVal":"Continuous Casting"},{"skID":"9541","skVal":"Contrast"},{"skID":"9542","skVal":"Contrast Agents"},{"skID":"9640","skVal":"Cook A Tasty Meal"},{"skID":"10506","skVal":"Critical Infrastructure"},{"skID":"10507","skVal":"Critical Infrastructure Protection"},{"skID":"11126","skVal":"Cyberinfrastructure"},{"skID":"11298","skVal":"Data Center Infrastructure"},{"skID":"11348","skVal":"Data Infrastructure"},{"skID":"11495","skVal":"DataStage"},{"skID":"11496","skVal":"Datastage 8.1"},{"skID":"11497","skVal":"Datastream"},{"skID":"11910","skVal":"Demand Forecasting"},{"skID":"12485","skVal":"Die Casting"},{"skID":"12543","skVal":"Digital Broadcast"},{"skID":"12805","skVal":"Disaster"},{"skID":"12806","skVal":"Disaster Management"},{"skID":"12807","skVal":"Disaster Medicine"},{"skID":"12808","skVal":"Disaster Preparedness"},{"skID":"12809","skVal":"Disaster Recovery"},{"skID":"12810","skVal":"Disaster Response"},{"skID":"12811","skVal":"Disaster Risk Reduction"},{"skID":"13118","skVal":"DNAStar"},{"skID":"13705","skVal":"Dynasty Trusts"},{"skID":"13731","skVal":"E-blast"},{"skID":"13732","skVal":"E-blasts"},{"skID":"13809","skVal":"E-Waste"},{"skID":"13902","skVal":"East"},{"skID":"13903","skVal":"East Africa"},{"skID":"13904","skVal":"East Asia"},{"skID":"13905","skVal":"East Asian affairs"},{"skID":"13906","skVal":"East Asian Studies"},{"skID":"13907","skVal":"East Coast Swing"},{"skID":"13908","skVal":"Eastern Europe"},{"skID":"13909","skVal":"Eastern Philosophy"},{"skID":"13934","skVal":"Eblasts"},{"skID":"13962","skVal":"Ecclesiastical"},{"skID":"14030","skVal":"Economic Forecasting"},{"skID":"14306","skVal":"Elastic Load Balancing"},{"skID":"14307","skVal":"Elastic Reality"},{"skID":"14308","skVal":"Elasticity"},{"skID":"14309","skVal":"ElasticSearch"},{"skID":"14310","skVal":"Elastix"},{"skID":"14311","skVal":"Elastomers"},{"skID":"14539","skVal":"Email Infrastructure"},{"skID":"14999","skVal":"Engineering Plastics"},{"skID":"15096","skVal":"Enterprise IT Infrastructure"},{"skID":"15167","skVal":"Enthusiast"},{"skID":"15168","skVal":"Enthusiastic"},{"skID":"15169","skVal":"Enthusiastic self-starter"},{"skID":"15708","skVal":"Europe, the Middle East, and Africa (EMEA)"},{"skID":"16271","skVal":"Eyeblaster"},{"skID":"16283","skVal":"Eze Castle"},{"skID":"16353","skVal":"Facial Plastic & Reconstructive Surgery"},{"skID":"16358","skVal":"Facilita Forecast"},{"skID":"16376","skVal":"Facility Master Planning"},{"skID":"16500","skVal":"Far East"},{"skID":"16501","skVal":"Far East sourcing"},{"skID":"16529","skVal":"Fashion Forecasting"},{"skID":"16542","skVal":"Fast"},{"skID":"16543","skVal":"Fast Casual"},{"skID":"16544","skVal":"Fast Data"},{"skID":"16545","skVal":"FAST ESP"},{"skID":"16546","skVal":"Fast Ethernet"},{"skID":"16547","skVal":"Fast Food"},{"skID":"16548","skVal":"Fast Formula"},{"skID":"16549","skVal":"Fast Growth"},{"skID":"16550","skVal":"Fast Leaner"},{"skID":"16551","skVal":"Fast Learner"},{"skID":"16552","skVal":"Fast Learning"},{"skID":"16553","skVal":"Fast Pace"},{"skID":"16554","skVal":"Fast Paced Environment"},{"skID":"16555","skVal":"Fast Paced Environments"},{"skID":"16556","skVal":"Fast Service"},{"skID":"16557","skVal":"Fast Tax"},{"skID":"16558","skVal":"Fast Thinker"},{"skID":"16559","skVal":"Fast Thinking"},{"skID":"16560","skVal":"Fast Track"},{"skID":"16561","skVal":"Fast Turn Around"},{"skID":"16562","skVal":"Fast Turnaround"},{"skID":"16563","skVal":"Fast Worker"},{"skID":"16564","skVal":"Fast-Moving Consumer Goods (FMCG)"},{"skID":"16565","skVal":"Fast-paced"},{"skID":"16566","skVal":"Fast-paced Environments"},{"skID":"16567","skVal":"FASTA"},{"skID":"16568","skVal":"Fastcase"},{"skID":"16569","skVal":"FastCGI"},{"skID":"16570","skVal":"Fastdata"},{"skID":"16571","skVal":"Fasteners"},{"skID":"16572","skVal":"Fastening Systems"},{"skID":"16573","skVal":"FastExport"},{"skID":"16574","skVal":"Fastlane"},{"skID":"16575","skVal":"FastLoad"},{"skID":"16576","skVal":"FASTR"},{"skID":"16577","skVal":"Fastrack"},{"skID":"16578","skVal":"Fastscan"},{"skID":"16579","skVal":"FastStats"},{"skID":"16580","skVal":"FastT"},{"skID":"16581","skVal":"FastTax"},{"skID":"16582","skVal":"FastTrack"},{"skID":"17073","skVal":"Financial Forecasting"},{"skID":"17158","skVal":"Financially Astute"},{"skID":"17538","skVal":"Flood Forecasting"},{"skID":"17575","skVal":"Flow Master"},{"skID":"17586","skVal":"Flowmaster"},{"skID":"17794","skVal":"Forecast Modeling"},{"skID":"17795","skVal":"Forecast Pro"},{"skID":"17796","skVal":"Forecasting"},{"skID":"17797","skVal":"Forecasting Models"},{"skID":"18350","skVal":"Fundmaster"},{"skID":"18578","skVal":"Gastric Bypass"},{"skID":"18579","skVal":"Gastro"},{"skID":"18580","skVal":"Gastroenterology"},{"skID":"18581","skVal":"Gastrointestinal"},{"skID":"18582","skVal":"Gastrointestinal Disorders"},{"skID":"18583","skVal":"Gastrointestinal Surgery"},{"skID":"18584","skVal":"Gastronomy"},{"skID":"18585","skVal":"GastroPlus"},{"skID":"19080","skVal":"Glass Casting"},{"skID":"19166","skVal":"Global Infrastructure Management"},{"skID":"19452","skVal":"Google Webmaster Tools"},{"skID":"19697","skVal":"Graston"},{"skID":"19698","skVal":"Graston Technique"},{"skID":"19699","skVal":"Graston Technique Certified"},{"skID":"19751","skVal":"Green Infrastructure"},{"skID":"20034","skVal":"Gymnastics"},{"skID":"20230","skVal":"Hardware Infrastructure"},{"skID":"20313","skVal":"Hazardous Waste Management"},{"skID":"20315","skVal":"Hazelcast"},{"skID":"21292","skVal":"HP Master ASE"},{"skID":"21802","skVal":"Icecast"},{"skID":"22106","skVal":"Imagecast"},{"skID":"22493","skVal":"Industrial Waste Management"},{"skID":"22494","skVal":"Industrial Wastewater"},{"skID":"22690","skVal":"Infrastructure"},{"skID":"22691","skVal":"Infrastructure Capacity Planning"},{"skID":"22692","skVal":"Infrastructure Consolidation"},{"skID":"22693","skVal":"Infrastructure des r?seaux et s?curit?"},{"skID":"22694","skVal":"Infrastructure Management"},{"skID":"22695","skVal":"Infrastructure Optimization"},{"skID":"22696","skVal":"Infrastructure Planning"},{"skID":"22697","skVal":"Infrastructure Security"},{"skID":"22698","skVal":"Infrastructure Services"},{"skID":"22699","skVal":"Infrastructure Solutions"},{"skID":"22700","skVal":"Infrastructure Technologies"},{"skID":"22701","skVal":"Infrastructure Transformation"},{"skID":"22702","skVal":"Infrastructure Upgrades"},{"skID":"22703","skVal":"Infrastucture"},{"skID":"22972","skVal":"Integrated Master Schedules"},{"skID":"23448","skVal":"Internet Infrastructure"},{"skID":"23571","skVal":"Intrastat"},{"skID":"23617","skVal":"Inventory Forecasting"},{"skID":"23652","skVal":"Investment Casting"},{"skID":"23754","skVal":"IP Multicast"},{"skID":"24082","skVal":"IT Infrastructure"},{"skID":"24083","skVal":"IT Infrastructure Design"},{"skID":"24084","skVal":"IT Infrastructure Management"},{"skID":"24085","skVal":"IT Infrastructure Operations"},{"skID":"24150","skVal":"Item Master"},{"skID":"24620","skVal":"Jumpmaster"},{"skID":"25023","skVal":"Kyphoplasty"},{"skID":"25239","skVal":"Lantastic"},{"skID":"25343","skVal":"Last Mile"},{"skID":"25344","skVal":"Last.fm"},{"skID":"25345","skVal":"Lasting Powers of Attorney"},{"skID":"25346","skVal":"Lasting Relationships"},{"skID":"25347","skVal":"LastPass"},{"skID":"25348","skVal":"LastWord"},{"skID":"25625","skVal":"Least Cost Routing"},{"skID":"25633","skVal":"Leave No Trace Master Educator"},{"skID":"25900","skVal":"Licensed Master Electrician"},{"skID":"25925","skVal":"Life Casting"},{"skID":"26247","skVal":"Live Broadcast"},{"skID":"26570","skVal":"Loss Forecasting"},{"skID":"26579","skVal":"Lost Wax Casting"},{"skID":"27200","skVal":"Managing IT Infrastructure"},{"skID":"27601","skVal":"MASTAN"},{"skID":"27602","skVal":"Master Agreements"},{"skID":"27603","skVal":"Master Builder"},{"skID":"27604","skVal":"Master Classes"},{"skID":"27605","skVal":"Master Colorist"},{"skID":"27606","skVal":"Master Communicator"},{"skID":"27607","skVal":"Master Control"},{"skID":"27608","skVal":"Master Data"},{"skID":"27609","skVal":"Master Data Management"},{"skID":"27610","skVal":"Master Diver"},{"skID":"27611","skVal":"Master Franchising"},{"skID":"27612","skVal":"Master Gardener"},{"skID":"27613","skVal":"Master Level"},{"skID":"27614","skVal":"Master Mason"},{"skID":"27615","skVal":"Master Networker"},{"skID":"27616","skVal":"Master of presentations"},{"skID":"27617","skVal":"Master Peace Officer"},{"skID":"27618","skVal":"Master Plan"},{"skID":"27619","skVal":"Master Planned Communities"},{"skID":"27620","skVal":"Master Plans"},{"skID":"27621","skVal":"Master Practitioner"},{"skID":"27622","skVal":"Master Schedule"},{"skID":"27623","skVal":"Master Scheduling"},{"skID":"27624","skVal":"Master Scuba Diver"},{"skID":"27625","skVal":"Master Site Planning"},{"skID":"27626","skVal":"Master Suites"},{"skID":"27627","skVal":"Master-planning"},{"skID":"27628","skVal":"Masterbuilder"},{"skID":"27629","skVal":"Mastercam"},{"skID":"27630","skVal":"MasterCard"},{"skID":"27631","skVal":"Mastering"},{"skID":"27632","skVal":"Mastermind"},{"skID":"27633","skVal":"Mastermind Groups"},{"skID":"27634","skVal":"Masterminding"},{"skID":"27635","skVal":"Masterpiece"},{"skID":"27636","skVal":"Masterplanner"},{"skID":"27637","skVal":"Masterplanning"},{"skID":"27638","skVal":"Masterplans"},{"skID":"27639","skVal":"Masters Certificate in Project Management"},{"skID":"27640","skVal":"MasterSpec"},{"skID":"27641","skVal":"MasterTax"},{"skID":"27642","skVal":"Mastery"},{"skID":"28201","skVal":"MegaStat"},{"skID":"28223","skVal":"Member of Toastmasters"},{"skID":"28392","skVal":"Messaging Infrastructure"},{"skID":"28447","skVal":"Metastock"},{"skID":"28448","skVal":"Metastorm"},{"skID":"28639","skVal":"Microsoft Forecaster"},{"skID":"28641","skVal":"Microsoft Infrastructure"},{"skID":"28642","skVal":"Microsoft infrastructure technologies"},{"skID":"28742","skVal":"Middle East"},{"skID":"28743","skVal":"Middle East Politics"},{"skID":"28744","skVal":"Middle Eastern history"},{"skID":"28745","skVal":"Middle Eastern Studies"},{"skID":"28845","skVal":"Mimecast"},{"skID":"29094","skVal":"Mobile Infrastructure"},{"skID":"29188","skVal":"Model Casting"},{"skID":"29302","skVal":"Molecular Gastronomy"},{"skID":"29898","skVal":"Multicast"},{"skID":"30090","skVal":"MusicMaster"},{"skID":"30248","skVal":"Narrowcasting"},{"skID":"30260","skVal":"Nastran"},{"skID":"30320","skVal":"Natural Disasters"},{"skID":"30426","skVal":"Near East"},{"skID":"30468","skVal":"NEi Nastran"},{"skID":"30626","skVal":"Network Infrastructure"},{"skID":"30627","skVal":"Network Infrastructure Architecture"},{"skID":"30680","skVal":"Networking Infrastructure"},{"skID":"30691","skVal":"Netzwerk-Infrastruktur und Sicherheit"},{"skID":"30924","skVal":"Newport Coast"},{"skID":"31366","skVal":"Nuclear Waste Management"},{"skID":"31534","skVal":"Observational Astronomy"},{"skID":"31590","skVal":"Oculoplastic Surgery"},{"skID":"31768","skVal":"Oil Pastel"},{"skID":"32882","skVal":"Otoplasty"},{"skID":"32949","skVal":"Outside Broadcast"},{"skID":"33077","skVal":"P&L Forecasting"},{"skID":"33162","skVal":"PADI Divemaster"},{"skID":"33539","skVal":"Past Clients"},{"skID":"33540","skVal":"Past Life Regression"},{"skID":"33541","skVal":"Past Lives"},{"skID":"33542","skVal":"Past Perfect"},{"skID":"33543","skVal":"Past Performance"},{"skID":"33544","skVal":"Pasta"},{"skID":"33545","skVal":"Paste-up"},{"skID":"33546","skVal":"Pastel"},{"skID":"33547","skVal":"Pastel Accounting"},{"skID":"33548","skVal":"Pastel Evolution"},{"skID":"33549","skVal":"Pastel Partner"},{"skID":"33550","skVal":"Pasteurization"},{"skID":"33551","skVal":"Pastoral"},{"skID":"33552","skVal":"Pastoral Care"},{"skID":"33553","skVal":"Pastoral Counseling"},{"skID":"33554","skVal":"Pastoral Theology"},{"skID":"33555","skVal":"Pastoring"},{"skID":"33556","skVal":"Pastors"},{"skID":"33557","skVal":"PastPerfect"},{"skID":"33558","skVal":"Pastry"},{"skID":"34223","skVal":"Pertmaster"},{"skID":"34351","skVal":"Phase Contrast"},{"skID":"34369","skVal":"PHAST"},{"skID":"34817","skVal":"Planning Budgeting & Forecasting"},{"skID":"34884","skVal":"Plaster"},{"skID":"34885","skVal":"Plaster Casting"},{"skID":"34886","skVal":"Plastering"},{"skID":"34887","skVal":"Plastic Cards"},{"skID":"34888","skVal":"Plastic Design"},{"skID":"34889","skVal":"Plastic Extrusion"},{"skID":"34890","skVal":"Plastic Part Design"},{"skID":"34891","skVal":"Plastic Surgery"},{"skID":"34892","skVal":"Plastic Welding"},{"skID":"34893","skVal":"Plasticity"},{"skID":"34894","skVal":"Plastics"},{"skID":"34895","skVal":"Plastics Compounding"},{"skID":"34896","skVal":"Plastics Engineering"},{"skID":"34897","skVal":"Plastics Industry"},{"skID":"34898","skVal":"Plastics Recycling"},{"skID":"35030","skVal":"Podcast Production"},{"skID":"35031","skVal":"Podcasting"},{"skID":"35584","skVal":"Practice Master"},{"skID":"35653","skVal":"Precast"},{"skID":"35843","skVal":"Price Elasticity"},{"skID":"35844","skVal":"Price Forecasting"},{"skID":"35954","skVal":"Printmaster"},{"skID":"36238","skVal":"Procrastination"},{"skID":"36303","skVal":"Product Forecasting"},{"skID":"36413","skVal":"Production Forecasting"},{"skID":"37205","skVal":"Public Broadcasting"},{"skID":"37229","skVal":"Public Infrastructure"},{"skID":"37620","skVal":"Quantcast"},{"skID":"37876","skVal":"Radio Astronomy"},{"skID":"37877","skVal":"Radio Broadcasting"},{"skID":"37900","skVal":"Radioactive Waste Management"},{"skID":"38040","skVal":"Raster"},{"skID":"38041","skVal":"Rasterino"},{"skID":"38109","skVal":"RCS Master Control"},{"skID":"38781","skVal":"Remote Infrastructure Management"},{"skID":"39057","skVal":"Resin Casting"},{"skID":"39328","skVal":"Revenue Forecasting"},{"skID":"39442","skVal":"Rhinoplasty"},{"skID":"39644","skVal":"Roasting"},{"skID":"39822","skVal":"Roxio Toast"},{"skID":"39823","skVal":"Roy Morgan Asteroid"},{"skID":"40279","skVal":"SAM Broadcaster"},{"skID":"40312","skVal":"Sandblasting"},{"skID":"40313","skVal":"Sandcastle"},{"skID":"40760","skVal":"Screencasting"},{"skID":"41014","skVal":"Security Infrastructure"},{"skID":"41120","skVal":"Self Mastery"},{"skID":"41803","skVal":"Shoutcast"},{"skID":"41884","skVal":"SigmaStat"},{"skID":"41951","skVal":"Silverfast"},{"skID":"41952","skVal":"SilverFast HDR Studio"},{"skID":"42106","skVal":"Site Waste Management Plans"},{"skID":"42244","skVal":"Slip Casting"},{"skID":"42748","skVal":"Software Infrastructure"},{"skID":"42892","skVal":"Solid Waste"},{"skID":"43085","skVal":"South East Asia"},{"skID":"43219","skVal":"Special Master"},{"skID":"43441","skVal":"Sports Enthusiast"},{"skID":"43960","skVal":"Steadfast"},{"skID":"44043","skVal":"Stochastic Analysis"},{"skID":"44044","skVal":"Stochastic Calculus"},{"skID":"44045","skVal":"Stochastic Control"},{"skID":"44046","skVal":"Stochastic Differential Equations"},{"skID":"44047","skVal":"Stochastic Methods"},{"skID":"44048","skVal":"Stochastic Modeling"},{"skID":"44049","skVal":"Stochastic Optimization"},{"skID":"44050","skVal":"Stochastic Processes"},{"skID":"44051","skVal":"Stochastic Programming"},{"skID":"44052","skVal":"Stochastic Simulation"},{"skID":"44228","skVal":"Strategic Forecasting"},{"skID":"44998","skVal":"Sustainable Infrastructure"},{"skID":"45143","skVal":"Synaptic Plasticity"},{"skID":"45160","skVal":"Syndicaster"},{"skID":"45467","skVal":"Talent Casting"},{"skID":"45596","skVal":"Task Master"},{"skID":"45599","skVal":"Taste"},{"skID":"45954","skVal":"Technically Astute"},{"skID":"46110","skVal":"Telecom Infrastructure"},{"skID":"46566","skVal":"Thermoplastic Elastomers"},{"skID":"46567","skVal":"Thermoplastics"},{"skID":"46653","skVal":"Thrive in A Fast-paced Environment"},{"skID":"46695","skVal":"Ticketmaster"},{"skID":"46887","skVal":"Toast"},{"skID":"46888","skVal":"Toastmasters"},{"skID":"47106","skVal":"TraceMaster"},{"skID":"47583","skVal":"Trend Forecasting"},{"skID":"47632","skVal":"Tricaster"},{"skID":"48059","skVal":"Ultrafast Spectroscopy"},{"skID":"48131","skVal":"Unicast"},{"skID":"48533","skVal":"Vaastu"},{"skID":"48566","skVal":"Validation Master Plans"},{"skID":"48667","skVal":"VAST"},{"skID":"48727","skVal":"Vedic Astrology"},{"skID":"48783","skVal":"Venetian Plaster"},{"skID":"48985","skVal":"Video Podcasts"},{"skID":"49001","skVal":"Video Toaster"},{"skID":"49088","skVal":"Virtual Desktop Infrastructure"},{"skID":"49152","skVal":"Viscoelasticity"},{"skID":"49163","skVal":"Vision Casting"},{"skID":"49173","skVal":"Vision-casting"},{"skID":"49342","skVal":"VMware Infrastructure"},{"skID":"49379","skVal":"Vodcasting"},{"skID":"49380","skVal":"Vodcasts"},{"skID":"49387","skVal":"Voice Broadcasting"},{"skID":"49388","skVal":"Voice Casting"},{"skID":"49434","skVal":"Volume Forecasting"},{"skID":"49649","skVal":"Waste"},{"skID":"49650","skVal":"Waste Audits"},{"skID":"49651","skVal":"Waste Characterization"},{"skID":"49652","skVal":"Waste Disposal"},{"skID":"49653","skVal":"Waste Heat Recovery"},{"skID":"49654","skVal":"Waste Management"},{"skID":"49655","skVal":"Waste Reduction"},{"skID":"49656","skVal":"Waste to Energy"},{"skID":"49657","skVal":"Waste Treatment"},{"skID":"49658","skVal":"Waste Water Treatment"},{"skID":"49659","skVal":"Waste Water Treatment Plants"},{"skID":"49660","skVal":"Wastewater"},{"skID":"49661","skVal":"Wastewater Treatment"},{"skID":"49662","skVal":"Wastewater Treatment Design"},{"skID":"49671","skVal":"Water & Wastewater Design"},{"skID":"49823","skVal":"Weather Forecasting"},{"skID":"49856","skVal":"Web Broadcasting"},{"skID":"49905","skVal":"Web Infrastructure"},{"skID":"49989","skVal":"Webcasting"},{"skID":"50021","skVal":"Webmaster Services"},{"skID":"50185","skVal":"West Coast Swing"},{"skID":"50501","skVal":"Wine Tasting"},{"skID":"50560","skVal":"Wirecast"},{"skID":"50703","skVal":"Wordfast"},{"skID":"50728","skVal":"Work in A Fast Pace Environment"},{"skID":"50729","skVal":"Work in A Fast Paced Environment"},{"skID":"50730","skVal":"Work in A Fast-paced Environment"},{"skID":"50810","skVal":"Working in a fast-paced environment"},{"skID":"50977","skVal":"Writing For Broadcast"},{"skID":"51308","skVal":"Yeast"},{"skID":"51309","skVal":"Yeast two-hybrid"},{"skID":"51411","skVal":"Zero Waste"}]
```

Comment: Did you figured it out? I'm having the same issue while using ember-select-2 with Ajax Queries.

Comment: Nope i didn't figured it out...

Comment: yoiu are missing the mapping for value and key that would be used by select